# why valueOf(null) calls the constructor valueOf(char[])

Tags: java, string, value-of

```
String.valueOf(null);
```

1. why `valueOf(char[] c)` is called and why not `valueOf(Object o);`
   ??
2. Why `String.valueOf(null);` produces a `NullPointerException` and
   `String.valueOf((Object)null);` do not produce any exception?

Comment: Because valueOf(char[] data) is the first method that null could be adapted to (as an Array is an Object).

Comment: The most specific method will be called. `null` is not an Object, making `char[] c` more specific.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun `null` *is* an Object as in being assignment-compatible with the type `Object`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't understand that. AFAIK, `null` is not an Object, actually it's the "absence" of an Object.

Comment: OP, as for your 2., would a Javadoc quote satisfy you, or do you want to pry open JDK API designers' heads?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun How is `char[]` more specific for something that is the absence of an object?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Apparently.. :) Well.. `null` is special.. I was inaccurate when I said it's the "absence" of an Object.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun The answer to that is: the `null` type is sort-of the *bottom type* of Java. As such `char[]` is more specific than `Object`. And while we're discussing static type arithmetic, it is definitely acceptable to call `null` a kind of `Object`, being a value whose type is the subtype of `Object`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Always there for good explanations and comments, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever more than one overloaded methos would be a possible target the most specific one possible would be used.

So if you pass in a `char[]` then `valueOf(char[])` and `valueOf(Object)` would be possible, but `valueOf(char[])` is more specific. Therefore that one will be called.

Now `null` is kind-of strange because it's a legal value for every non-primitive type, so it could be an argument to any of those methods. And *still* `valueOf(char[])` is more specific than `valueOf(Object)`, therefore the first one will be called.

Comment: A corollary to this is that if there is no single most specific overload (e.g. if there were also `valueOf(String)` - no one option is more specific than _all_ the other ones) then you'd get a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

`String.valueOf((Object) null)` calls the following method:

```java
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

As you can see, the *null case* is managed.

`String.valueOf(null)` calls the following method:

```java
public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
    return new String(data);
}
```

Which itself calls:

```java
public String(char value[]) {
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = value.length; // <-- NPE
    this.value = StringValue.from(value);
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation of the what, it doesn't really cover the why though